# Hyperlink to a mathjax script

Tags: hyperlink, mathjax

Using `\begin{equation}\label{name} ... \end{equation}`, one may write `<a href="#mjx-eqn-name">hyperlink to name</a>` to link to the equation.

Is there a similar way to link to `<script type="math/tex">\label{name}</script>`? I tried `href="#mjx-eqn-name"` and `href="#mjx-name"`, and even `href="#name"` with no success. I even tried `<script type="math/tex" id="name>...` with no success. So is this possible, or do I have to rely on `\begin{equation}...`?

Comment: Are you looking for `\ref`? http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Sorta. I want to use HTML syntax, which is the reason I use `<script>` instead of `\begin`. Is there a HTML style `\ref` equivalent?

Comment: OK, that's a pure HTML question then. Since script tags are not rendered you effectively cannot link to them.

Comment: You could use MathJax's nonstandard `\cssId`, http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#html to wrap around the equation content inside the script.